# How to cache results in datatables for already-viewed pages, while using server-side processing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching, datatables

I'm using server-side processing with datatables. When I click on page 2, it makes another server request, as usual. However, when I go back to page 1, I don't want it to make another request--I want it to use the same results from before.

Note that I am NOT talking about [pipelining](http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html), as described here. I'm not trying to load more results than are needed at once. I just want it to cache the results which have already been viewed.

Comment: So [set the correct headers](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/) on the responses issued by the server so that content is cached by the browser.

Comment: what if the page1 data changes while looking at page2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051088/allow-server-side-caching-in-fnserverdata-in-datatables

Comment: @spender hmm maybe I will have to go that route.

Comment: @dandavis well, originally I thought that I could get datatables to cache the results for that one datatables instantiation. The data could change, but if I wanted up-to-date data, I would just reload the page entirely (thus wiping cache).

Comment: @charlietfl that's for the old version of DataTables. Do you know of a solution for >1.10?

Comment: looking at the link and the new docs, i realized you can actually just modify the pipelining example to not fetch more than your visible rows; it's all setup as-shown to repaint page1 without a trip to the server... maybe even just change " pages: 5" to " pages: 1" and it will be everything you want. maybe, but knowing DataTables, prolly not ;)